# What causes RTTI to violate the Open-Closed Principle?

Tags: java, oop, rtti, open-closed-principle

For your reference, the Open-Closed Principle (OCP): https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/downing/papers/OCP.pdf

So I am almost done with my OOP course and I have a question about the OCP and why RTTI violates it. I have an idea, but I just want to make sure that I'm correct.

RTTI *doesn't* invalidate the OCP principle when you use it to infer whether or not something is of the base-class (supertype's) type, as in overriding the `equals(o: Object)` method in the superclass and using RTTI to check if the type of `o` is of the same type.

Are there similar cases of this where RTTI *doesn't* invalidate OCP?

Finally, are the cases where RTTI *does* invalidate OCP when you check for an instance of a *sub*type within the *super*type, thus modifying the supertype's source code and invalidating OCP (it clearly wasn't closed for modification)?

Comment: Wrong, observe Listings 9 and 10. Both use a downcast, but one usage is unsafe while the other is safe.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès well...isn't that because in (Listing 10) **Square** we are only type-checking for **Square** itself, whereas in Listing 9 we are checking for subtypes (**Circle** and **Square**)?

Comment: No. In L.9, it is claimed to draw everything but only draw square and circle, then a modification of this code is necessary if you add new subclasses of shapes. In L.10, it is claimed to draw squares and it is the case, every squares, even subtypes (colored squares, filled squares, or whatever) without changing anything. Rename function in L.9 draw squares and circles and it will be ok.

Comment: Ah that makes sense to me now...so the issue is that the way the superclass (Shape) and its function (DrawAllShapes) were written entails that in the future they will need to be modified when more subclasses are added, correct? So in this example we can swap-out RTTI for anything that would deal with these new subclasses and the issue remains the same.